# PHP: Getting random combinations to specified input

Tags: php

I am trying to display possibilities for additions of specific numbers but have not been getting the right results.

```
<?php

$num3 = 20;
$set = null;
$balance = $num3;

    $dig = mt_rand(1,5);
    for($i = $balance; $i > 0; $i -= $dig ){
        echo $dig.'<br>';
        if($i < 1){
            $set .= $i;
            $balance = 0;
        }
        else{
            $set .= $dig.'+';
            $dig = mt_rand(1,5);
        }
    }
echo $set.'='.$num3;
?>
```

Here are some of the outputs:

```
2+5+1+4+5+3+=20
1+4+3+5+3+=20
3+1+1+2+3+4+4+1+3+=20
```

Appreciate any pointers. Thank in advance...

Comment: And what would be "right result" by your definition?

Comment: That the sum of numbers would be the specified number, in this case, 20.

Comment: And the algorithm should only do that once, or merely find all possible solutions? Or find the shortest term? Or any random term that fulfills the equation?

Comment: it should return a combination randomly at any one time... As long as they add up to the specified given number...

Comment: Ok. See my answer below..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, even though the requirement isn't completely clear, here's an approach:
(edit: demonstrating prevention of endless loop)

```
$max_loops = 1000; 
$balance = 20;
$found = [];
while($balance > 0 && $max_loops-- > 0) {
    $r = mt_rand(1, 5);
    if ($balance - $r >= 0) {
        $found[] = $r;
        $balance -= $r;
    }
}
echo implode(' + ', $found) . ' = '.array_sum($found);
```

Note: This code has a small risk of getting caught in an endless loop... though it's doubtful that it'll ever happen :)

Edit: Now the loop contains a hard-limit of 1000 iterations, after which the loop will end for sure...

To provoke an endless loop, set `$balance = 7` and modify `mt_rand(4, 5)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a recursive function for this:

```
function randomAddends($target, $maxAddend = 5, $sum = 0, $addends = [])
{
    // Return the array of addends when the target is reached
    if ($target <= $sum) {
        return $addends;
    }

    // generate a new random addend and add it to the array
    $randomAddend = mt_rand(1, min($maxAddend, $target - $sum));
    $addends[] = $randomAddend;

    // make the recursive call with the new sum
    return randomAddends($target, $maxAddend, $sum + $randomAddend, $addends);
}
```

Comment: Yes, also a possible solution. Extra point for the reduction of the random-number range, once the difference of sum to the target gets below the former upper limit. It'll effectively eliminate the chance of an endless recursion.

Comment: Yes, I believe the depth will always be <= target, though statistically it will be much less (depending on the max addend)